# Type 'FirebaseAuth' has no member 'showTextInputPrompt'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the official firebase authentication documentation for swift available here:

I am trying to log the user in using a verification a code sent to their device. (using reCAPTCHA verification)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth, and I get this the error: "Type 'FirebaseAuth' has no member 'showTextInputPrompt'"

[image] Image containing the code snippet causing the error.

I just want to know more about this ".showTextInputPrompt" and where it comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`showTextInputPrompt` is not a member of FirebaseAuth. It's a member of the view controller from the example that code snippet is taken from.  See the full code at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/LegacyAuthQuickstart/AuthenticationExampleSwift/MainViewController.swift

**UPDATE**

I've updated the quickstart with a Swift implementation of `showTextInputPrompt`. See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/LegacyAuthQuickstart/AuthenticationExampleSwift/UIViewController.swift.

Comment: What swift version is that? because I have tried to access that function using the UIViewController, but it is not being recognized?!

Comment: It's defined locally in that project. The Swift MainViewController extends an Objective C implementation where it's implemented at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/AuthenticationExample/UIViewController%2BAlerts.m#L86

Comment: Updated the answer with a pointer to a new Swift implementation.

Comment: The links are broken